# How can I detect if the computer power is suspended in javascript?

Tags: javascript, html

Is there a reliable way to check from an open webpage with javascript if a laptop has been suspended (laptop lid closed/opened)?

Comment: No. You can monitor key presses and mouse moves though to check for user activity. Also see the `PageVisibility` [HTML5 API](http://www.html5rocks.com/en/tutorials/pagevisibility/intro/)

Comment: why do you wan't to do this

Comment: [Discussion of this question can be found here](http://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/191129/how-could-i-have-avoided-this-question-being-put-on-hold)

Comment: I've marked this as a duplicate, instead. Although the target question uses the word "Desktop", it simply means that as opposed to a mobile device.

Answer (score 8, accepted):

I have managed to achieve this by using a javascript interval that checks how much time has passed. If the power is suspended then the time difference between ticks is off.

```
  <script>
    var last = (new Date()).getTime();

    setInterval(function(){
        var current = (new Date()).getTime();
        if (current-last > 3000) {
            console.log('power was suspended');
        }
        last = current;

    }, 1000);
  </script>
```

Comment: Incidentally, that's not the same thing your question asked for; perhaps you just worded the question differently than you meant? Your question seemed to be asking to detect if power **is** suspended, not **was**.

Comment: I think I'll go with this. I have a web page doing a long-poll to a server, and it seems screwed up after I suspend/resume the PC (connection lingers, but should have been closed). Need to evaluate this more, but I think that's what happens.

Answer (score 4):

Simply **no**. These are the kind of things that JavaScript isn't exposed to, for security reasons :). Same with the file system, although the File API gives some functionality.

It may also seem like this feature will lack usefulness, however, if it existed the website could do stuff "while you're not watching" which I don't believe is ever a good thing :)

The BatteryAPI as a few people mentioned in the comments is extremely important for some websites. For example, to know whether or not to run resource-consuming animations or functions, save all user data before he loses his work, etc. (especially when running on smartphones and tablets… not only laptops).

Comment: Maybe explain to him why

Comment: Yes i think you should explain why because, there is a battery api? right and closing the lid is slightly to do with battery, ie: standby. soo...

Comment: @Connor: There is a battery API?

Comment: I don't think it has much to do with security, maybe privacy. And that W3C/WHATWG didn't bother making an API for that (yet).

Comment: Allowing JavaScript to know such information is not responsible. Since JavaScript is a client-side language (node.js excluded), it is a security issue mainly.

Comment: @Matt well i have heard of it http://www.w3.org/TR/battery-status/ never looked into it though..

Comment: This isn't strictly true. http://stackoverflow.com/questions/17913785/how-can-i-detect-if-the-laptop-lid-is-closed-in-javascript/17913821#17913821

Comment: @Connor: Heh, from that you get [here](http://www.w3.org/TR/system-info-api/#idl-def-Display), which gives you whether the screen is "blanked" or not, so I guess the *actual* answer to the OP is "yes you can" (although I don't know any devices which support this :P).

Comment: In JS you can access the device's camera and microphone as long as the user gives permission to, "security" is hardly an excuse nowadays. Lack of usefulness to make an API solely for that I'd say.

Comment: @FabrícioMatté I agree with the lack of usfulness.. However someone can use it to do stuff while "you're not watching" like opening and closing browser windows to etc..

Comment: Okay, +1 for that point which I've overlooked. Even then, such an API would most likely have to request user permission first as the UserMedia API do. `=]`

Comment: @FabrícioMatté agreed. :)

Comment: You say "simply, no", but there is an answer on this page demonstrating exactly how to do this.

Answer (score 2):

@yotam-omer's answer isn't strictly true. While you can't detect the physical action of shutting the lid, you *can* detect leaving the page, and using polling to detect a loss of connection (i.e., shutting the lid). Pairing the two can be used to detect a loss of connection that isn't leaving the page.

If this sounds interesting, comment and I'll add an example.

Comment: This is the kind of thing i'm thinking of, I realise there isn't actually a browser API for whether the lid is closed ;-)

Comment: shutting the lid not always goes to sleep or hibernation.. that's user's preferences.. so there will be no loss of connection

Comment: Well, shutting the lid would be irrelevant to the application if it actually did nothing...

Comment: also if the computer is asleep its irrelevant to the application :)

Comment: Not always. 

@Tom Do you want me to add an example?

Comment: When you leave the page no javascript is running, so I don't understand your suggestion. How can JS be used to detect when it itself is no longer running?